# Alpine $watch to open the modal if there is error

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-8, watch, alpine.js

I would like to let the modal open if there is an error, so, I try to show *'have error'* with `console.log`, first, if there is an error to make sure it can watch the errors.

But, when I click submit and there are errors, *'have errors'* will not show in the console and when I change to `x-init="$watch('errors', value => open = true)"`,it will also not open.

I checked already there is an array for the `{{$errors}}`.

```
x-data="{  open: false, modal_1_open:false,modal_fam_open:false,modal_edu_open:false,modal_exp_open:false, errors:{{ $errors }}}" x-init="$watch('errors', value => console.log('have errors'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$watch` method for this because the `errors` Alpine.js variable is not changing on the frontend, therefore `$watch` will never fire. When you render the Blade template on the backend it produces the frontend code, not interacting with it in within the javascript runtime!

The solution is to put the log part of your code inside a Blade condition, like `@if` (depending the structure of `$errors`):

```
<div id="my_element" x-data="{open: false}"
     @if (count($errors) > 0)
     x-init="console.log('have errors')"  
     @endif
     >
<!-- Code of the modal component. -->
</div>
```

So when the `$errors` Blade variable is not empty, then we produce an `x-init` attribute, therefore Alpine.js will call the `console.log` method.

Comment: I write like this but it still not open when there are errors,could u please take a look for me what is the problem?`
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    x-init="{open:true}"  
    @endif`

Comment: Then show us more code. How does the Blade template look like? How do you set `$errors`? Where is the code for the modal? Etc. It's hard to debug when we can see only two attributes of the whole problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ 
Dauros
  I use open = true,can already ,thank you